# Dropdown displaying inside table cell

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to dynamically add rows to a table, and for each row I'd want to add a dropdown button so i can click on it and select an option to do some math on the row.

My solution was :

```
<script>
table = $('#myTable_input').DataTable();

let btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.innerHTML = "Compare";
btn.type = "button";
btn.className = "btn btn-light dropdown-toggle";
btn.setAttribute("style", "'z-index': '+100'");
btn.setAttribute("data-bs-toggle", "dropdown");
btn.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");

let ul = document.createElement("ul");
ul.className = 'dropdown-menu';
     
let li = document.createElement("li");
let option_a = document.createElement("a")

option_a.className = 'dropdown-item';
option_a.innerHTML = "Test1";

li.appendChild(option_a);            
li.appendChild(option_a);
ul.appendChild(li);
btn.appendChild(ul);

table.row.add([btn,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]).draw();
$(table.cell(0,0).node()).html(btn);
</script>
```

```
<style>
    
    li{
        transition: transform .1s;
    }
    
    li:hover{
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: scale(1.05);
    z-index: +1;
    position:relative;
    }
  
</style>
```

The thing is, my solution being already *very ugly*, it also displays the options of the dropdown inside the table, which makes it aterrible dropdown.

Is it possible to have it displayed outside of the table ?
Should i consider trying another way ?

[image: Terrible button being terrible]